# Reveal on scroll using jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll, animate.css

I have created a reveal on scroll function using jquery and `animate.css`.

I have to call this function to the div under the `window.scroll()` function.

What I wish to is to create a plugin of this where user can just call the plugin in `document.ready` function or in his js file. and user do not need to specify `window.scroll()` function.
so I wish to return a function.

Please explain me how to create a plugin out of this function.
here is my function or almost a plugin

```
var windowheight = $(window).height();
var scrollpostop = $(window).scrollTop();
var scroolposbottom = windowheight + scrollpostop; 
$.fn.revealonscroll = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('hidden-me')){
            $(this).css({'opacity': 0}).addClass('hidden-me');
        }
        var objectoffsettop = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        if(!$(this).hasClass('animation-complete')){
            if(scroolposbottom > objectoffsettop){
                var animationclass = $(this).data("animation");
                $(this).animate({'opacity': 1}).addClass('animated animation-complete').addClass(animationclass);
                //.addClass('animated animation-complete').addClass(animationclass)
            }           
        }
    });
}; //the revealonscroll function ends here

$(window).scroll(function(){
    windowheight = $(window).height();
    scrollpostop = $(window).scrollTop();
    scroolposbottom = windowheight + scrollpostop; 
    $('.brown, .violet, .cream').revealonscroll();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yogendrakarekar2015/p5muckqh/

Comment: Don't reinvent this yourself, see https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ or http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/. Just include the scripts and add the effect class on any element.

Comment: Thank you Wouter, I know this plugins. but I am  learing to create  a plugin so craeted it